# 2nd M2 drive being detected in BIOS but not in OS

Tags: windows-10, ssd, storage, nvme

```
Asus B550 Plus Tuf Gaming
AMD 5800X
Seagate IronWolf X2 - RAID 1
M2 WD SN850 0.5TB
M2 Sabrent SB-RKTQ-2TB
OS Windows 10
```

I've added the Sabrent NVME SSD and it gets picked up in BIOS just fine.
However, I cannot find a way to detect on Windows. Not via Disk Management and not via Driver Manager. See the following images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So does Device Manager show any malfunctioning, disabled or unknown devices? Have you tried with Linux yet?

Comment: Maybe your NVME drives are in raid mode ?

Comment: It looks as if you are running on Windows build-in basic device drivers (Standard NVMe device?). Update you motherboard/chipset driver to the latest. Also check the Asus driver pages to see if the 2nd M.2 slot needs an additional driver. (It may not be part of the main chipset, but provided by an extra chip that needs a separate driver.)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the standard NVMe driver. It is not _basic_. The controller is also on the SSD itself, not on the mainboard. M.2 slots do not need drivers. As far as NVMe is concerned, they are just PCIe slots.

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with the RAID mode than anything. But without a screenshot of disk management i can't determine anything.

Comment: RAID only applies to SATA devices.